# HTML to UNFORMATTED plain text?

Tags: linux, html

I'm looking for a way to convert a folder full of HTML files to plain text. What I want is for the text files to be as much as possible like what I'd get if I selected all the text in a web browser, copied it, and pasted the text into a plain text file.

NO, REALLY, I WANT UNFORMATTED PLAIN TEXT. All of the solutions that I'm finding produce Markdown or something that looks like it, or tries to preserve layout, or uses asterisks and underscores to indicate text formatting, or preserves the content of scripts in the output file, or some clever goddam thing.

All I want is the words written by the author in the order that the author wrote them. I don't even care if the processing converts all of the list items in a list into a single paragraph, or even collapses the entire document into a single paragraph. Any of this is much better than giving me anything at all other than the actual language contained in the document.

I'd love a terminal application or Python script, but I'll take anything I can get.

Comment: Tip: remove everything between `<` and `>`. I don't know `sed`, but I'm pretty sure it could do it.

Comment: yup, sed can do it, and a host of other utilities. This is a basic scrape for content I think, but you're not saying whether you want the header information - there's tags that don't show in the body, including javascripts and such not in tags. Can you clarify that what you want it just the text content of a page?

Comment: =D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @ Ele Munjeli Yep, just the text content. (=

Comment: @gronostaj That gets me closer, but isn't perfect: some tags (<p>, <br>) are whitespace and really should be converted into space characters, because they separate actual words (as in "Here are some lines<br>in a quote"). OTOH, some tags (like <script> for inline scripts) are or can be containers for things that don't count as "plain text."

Comment: The output isn't any better than `lynx -dump`, but just wanted to point out that [Xidel](https://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html) is a good tool for extracting text from HTML that isn't necessarily well-formed, using [XPath](https://devhints.io/xpath) selectors: `curl -L w3c.org | xidel -e '//body//text()' - | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[html2text](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/) is a Python script that converts a page of HTML into equivalent Markdown-structured text. html2text can be downloaded and run in any operating system that has Python installed. The html2text program is in the repositories of many Linux distributions and it can be run from the command-line like this:

```
html2text -style pretty input.html
```

This command not only converts the original html file to text, but it also does a pretty good job of making the plain text output easy to read. The headings look like headings, the lists look like lists, etc.

If you're having trouble with automatically converting tables from webpages to unformatted text this can be easily done with a modern markdown editor like [Typora](https://typora.io/) or [Mark Text](https://marktext.app/) GUI applications for Windows/Mac/Linux. Comparing these two applications Mark Text is better than Typora at accurately capturing everything on a webpage and Typora has a more user-friendly editor, so I use both applications. I use Mark Text as a webpage grabber, and then I copy/paste the markdown text I captured into Typora and use Typora to edit it.

Comment: Thought I was pretty clear about really not wanting any formatting characters at all in the output, including those generated by Markdown. =(

Comment: All the formatting of the plain text output is done automatically by html2text by very clever use of the space character (which does not count as formatting because the space character is not a special character). There are no markdown asterisks or underline characters or any garbage like that. Also if you don't like the pretty style, you can use the `-style compact` option instead and get rid of the indentations made with the space character too.

Answer (score 6):

Use `w3m -dump <page.html>`.

It will give you the text representation of the html file.

From the man page:

```
-dump  dump formatted page into stdout
```

Although is says `formatted`, the output is just plain text.

Comment: `lynx` also supports `-dump`.

Comment: Yes, and the very same is achievable with the good old lynx like this: lynx -dump  -nolist -nomargins

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by [Gombai Sándor](https://superuser.com/users/556625/gombai-s%C3%A1ndor), in a comment to [NZD's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1043232/154827):

```
lynx -dump -nolist -nomargins
```

When run from the command-line with a URL, it writes the output to stdout.  This seems to work very well.  `-nomargins` may not be supported if one only has access to an older version of `lynx` (i.e. Lynx Version 2.8.5rel.5 (29 Oct 2005) on an old UNIX).

The output appears quite free of markup and links, with some potential exceptions (the following list may not be typical or exhaustive):

- Extra white space does seem to occur in tabular data, and, at least in some cases, it appears while the white space is usually helpful for extracting the tabular data, it is occasionally inconsistent in ways that complicate parsing.
- While links are not dumped, visible text may output.  For example, footnote references may render as asterisks, or, on a wiki, clickables may render as the equivalent plain-text (without underlying URL).
- Some references may expand and output the alternate text.
- Unordered lists dump with asterisks and indentation.
- Order lists dump with numbers and indentation.
- Input fields may appear as underscores

Answer (score 1):

[Unix.com: How to remove only HTML tags in a file](http://www.unix.com/linux/45584-how-remove-only-html-tags-inside-file.html) provides:
`sed -n '/^$/!{s/<[^>]*>//g;p;}' filename`

or `html2text`

[CommandLineFu: Remove all HTML tags](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/7872/remove-all-html-tags-from-a-file) shows another `sed` line, or `awk`.

I believe this is a somewhat common operation provided by multiple programs, and that the most common name for this task is to "strip" the HTML.  A quick [Google Search for: Linux strip html tags](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=linux+strip+html+tags) shows multiple solutions, including [PHP: strip tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: I was going to suggest using something like `xmlstarlet` with an XPath like `//*/text()`, but some post-processing with sed was required anyway. So it's probably easier to just do it all in sed. `:)`

Comment: …although, as mentioned in the comments above, this doesn't account for tags like `<script>` which contain content that is not part of the visible text on the page, which the OP is pretty explicit about.